# Do Spark DataFrames/Datasets share data when cached?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, rdd

Let's say I do something like this:

```
def readDataset: Dataset[Row] = ???

val ds1 = readDataset.cache();

val ds2 = ds1.withColumn("new", lit(1)).cache();
```

Will `ds2` and `ds1` share all data in columns except *"new"* added to `ds2`? If I cache both datasets will it store in memory whole datasets `ds` and `ds2` or will shared data be stored only once?

If data is shared, then when this *sharing* is broken (so the same data is stored in two memory locations)?

I know that datasets and rdds are immutable, but I couldn't find clear anwsers if the share data or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short: **the cached data will not be shared**.

Experimental proof to convince you, with code snippet and corresponding memory usage that can be found in Spark UI:

```scala
val df = spark.range(10000000).cache()
val df2 = df.withColumn("other", col("id")*3)
df2.count()
```

uses about 10MB of memory:

[image]

while

```scala
val df = spark.range(10000000).cache()
val df2 = df.withColumn("other", col("id")*3).cache()
df2.count()
```

uses about 30MB:

- for `df`: 10MB
- for `df2`: 10MB for the copied column and another 10MB the new one:

[image]